# Vue two requests only one valid token

Tags: jwt, vue.js, vue-resource

I just startet with vue and vue resource.
In the backend I am using laravel, where I handle the jwt tokens.
The token is refreshed every request. So far this works great, except one situation:
If I send two requests in a row with vue resource like below:

```
 //first request
 Vue.http.get('/api/runs').then((response) => {

        return response.json();
    }, (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.$set('error', {'status' : response.status, 'error': response.statusText});
    });
//second request
Vue.http.get('/api/meta').then((response) => {

        return response.json();
    }, (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.$set('error', {'status' : response.status, 'error': response.statusText});
    });
```

only the first request has a valid token.
I am setting the token via the interceptor:

```
 Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
    request.headers['Authorization'] = Auth.getAuthHeader();
    request.emulateJSON = true;
    next(function(response) {
        if(response.headers['Authorization']) {
            var token = response.headers['Authorization'];
            localStorage.setItem('jwt-token', token);
        }
    });
});
```

This happens, because both requests are fired parallel before the interceptor can set the new jwt token. 
So my question is, how I can force the second request until the first has completely finished or how can I force the interceptor to wait?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can accomplish this, as you have it, with an interceptor. The Promises are asynchronous. You would need to put the second request into the success callback of the first request. However, I think that could get unnecessarily messy at some point and also takes away the async abilities from your calls.

I think the better solution is to create an endpoint in your backend API ([Laravel/Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#refreshing-tokens)) specifically for refreshing tokens. You'll need to send a `refresh_token` to the endpoint to get back your new `access_token`. Let the access tokens live longer (so you aren't refreshing them too heavily and slowing down your app). This is a typical OAuth2 flow. Here's a single interceptor (VueJS 2.0 and latest Vue-resource 1.0.3) that will add your Auth header and also automatically refresh tokens when the interceptor gets an invalid token response:

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
  const token = "get your token from localStorage or Vuex here"
  const hasAuthHeader = request.headers.has('Authorization')

  if (token && !hasAuthHeader) {
    request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
  }

  next((response) => {
    if (response.status === 401 && response.data.error === 'invalid_token') {
      // Create this function below to get the new token and store
      // it in localStorage and then retries the original request.
      return refreshToken(request)
    }
  })
})
```

I'll leave the `refreshToken(request)` function for you to write but hopefully you get the idea here. You can make adjustments and use JWTs. And you can take a look at my [VueJS 2.0 Example Project](https://github.com/prograhammer/example-vue-project) or more specifically the [Auth.js](https://github.com/prograhammer/example-vue-project#auth-script) file to see how I implemented the refresh token function.